# How to use the SPARQL CONSTRUCT in the new MeSH endpoint?

Tags: sparql, endpoint

I'm trying to use the construct CONSTRUCT in the SPARQL MeSH endpoint but this one always return an empty query. 
In particular i'm finding the alias of some medical names.

Basically the SELECT query that works is:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX meshv: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/vocab#>
PREFIX mesh: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/>
PREFIX mesh2015: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2015/>

SELECT ?d ?dName ?c ?cName 
FROM <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh>
WHERE {
  ?d a meshv:Descriptor .
  ?d meshv:concept ?c .
  ?d rdfs:label ?dName .
  ?c rdfs:label ?cName
  FILTER(REGEX(?dName,'infection','i') || REGEX(?cName,'infection','i')) 
} 
ORDER BY ?d
```

and i'm finding something as the following:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX meshv: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/vocab#>
PREFIX mesh: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/>
PREFIX mesh2015: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2015/>

CONSTRUCT{
            ?dName a (subject)
            is alias of (predicate)
            ?cName (object)
}
WHERE {
  ?d a meshv:Descriptor .
  ?d meshv:concept ?c .
  ?d rdfs:label ?dName .
  ?c rdfs:label ?cName
  FILTER(REGEX(?dName,'infection','i') || REGEX(?cName,'infection','i')) 
}
```

[Reference documents](http://hhs.github.io/meshrdf/sparql-and-uri-requests.html)
 informs that CONSTRUCT is supported and you can try to query [here](http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/query), the SPARQL endpoint should be [here](http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/sparql).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your second query isn't a legal SPARQL query.  I don't know MeSH is supposed to support something else, but the construct would need to use variables that appeared in the **where** part.  `construct { ?s ?p 42 } where { ?s ?p ?o }`.  Note that literals can't be the the subjects of RDF triples, and it's *likely* that the value of an `rdfs:label` property is a literal, so things like `construct { ?label ?p ?o } where { ?s ?p ?o ; rdfs:label ?label }` probably won't work.  What sort of error are you getting?

Comment: Hi @JoshuaTaylor thank you for your reply.  I can use also CONSTRUCT WHERE without specifying anything in between... but the result is always the same, the query does not give me any error in particular, gives me an empty table with written subject, predicate and object in the head.

Comment: `CONSTRUCT
WHERE {
  mesh:D015242 meshv:pharmacologicalAction ?pa .
  ?pa rdfs:label ?paLabel .
} ` ok this works... Mine is a conceptual problem. Thank you.